# MySQL, compare a set of records with another set

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on some kind of RNA probe data. For one probe, a *set* of RNA sequences are supplied, typically 20-40 sequences, e.g.

[image]

As can be seen from the picture, each sequence, within a set, is about 30 characters long.

When populating the database with NEW probes, a new set of sequences are supplied and associated with the new probe.

We will need to check and make sure that the new set of sequences are not the same as one that already exists in the database.

First test would be the number of sequences (the data above got 20). That is a simple test.

If the set size is equal, then we need to check each item within a set. However, the order of the items, within each set, are irrelevant.

Question is, does MySQL have an inbuilt command to check for equality between two sets, where the order of each item, in each set, is irrelevant?

Comment: Can you reduce these to something like a SHA2-256 hash to make comparisons easy? If order is irrelevant you'd have to sort before hashing to get consistent output.

Comment: Put the new set in a temporary table. Join the two tables on the `sequence` column. If the result of the join is the same size as the original table, then the two sets are equal.

Comment: Why not combine the sequences into a single column and use a unique index?

Comment: This kind of thing crops up every once in a while. Usually, after exhausting a bunch of ideas in sql, the OP decides to do the analysis in application code. That said, if you want to continue to explore the current avenue, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Presumably your table of EXISTING probes will have hundreds? thousands? millions? of RNA sequence sets that all need to be checked against the NEW probe to avoid duplicate sets being loaded?  Or is that not the situation?

Comment: @user9601310 There may be hundreds eventually, but not much more.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question, is "no", there's no built-in command in MySQL to check for equality. In some other databases, there is an INTERSECT or MINUS/EXCEPT operator that would do pretty much what you are asking for. I've made the assumption here that sequences within a probe are unique. The SQL below can probably be adapted to do the job.  I've prepared and tested a DBFiddle sample [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=83f0a460e45ba3536710ab17c815922a).  Basically what it does is joins all the sequences in the new probe to all the sequences in the existing probes, then checks to see if the number of records returned from the join is the same as the total count of records in the existing probe.  If the counts match, then the new probe is a duplicate. The query will return the id of the existing duplicate probe. HTH.

```
SELECT x.probe,
       COUNT(*) AS newrecs,
       proberecs
FROM   (SELECT a.probe,
               a.rnaseq
        FROM   rnaprobes a
               JOIN newprobe b
                 ON a.rnaseq = b.rnaseq) x
       JOIN (SELECT probe,
                    COUNT(*) AS proberecs
             FROM   rnaprobes
             GROUP  BY probe) c
         ON x.probe = c.probe
GROUP  BY x.probe
HAVING COUNT(*) = proberecs
```